# How to send an image in C# to client using async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, highcharts, bitmap

I have two C# applications. One is a Service the other one is a Client. My Service creates a Chart with HighCharts.NET. Then I send the Chart to an external server and get the chart as an image. This method needs to be async, because I have to wait untill I become the image from the server. Well, that works fine.
Here is the code:

```
    public async Task CreateChart(HttpMessage message)
    {
        var settings = new HighchartsSetting
        {
            ExportImageType = "png",
            ImageWidth = 1500,
            ServerAddress = "http://export.highcharts.com/"
        };

        var client = new HighchartsClient(settings);

        if (message.Message == "Request was successfully")
        {
            // Get Chart Data
            var results = getResults();

            var chartOptions = new
            {
                title = new
                {
                  text = "TestChart"  
                },
                xAxis = new
                {
                    categories =  getDates();
                },
                series = new[]
                {
                    new { data = getData() }
                }
            };

            var link = await client.GetChartImageFromOptionsAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartOptions));

            string preLink = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(link);

            string highChartsLink = "http://export.highcharts.com/" + preLink;

            byte[] file;
            using (var downloadClient = new WebClient())
            {
                file = downloadClient.DownloadData(highChartsLink);
            }
            _chartFile = file;
        }
```

As you see, now my Image is in byte[] format in the _chartFile variable.

Now i have my Controller:

```
  public async Task<Image> GetRequest([FromBody]ChartRequestModel body)
    {
        ....
        // Creates Chart based on request
        await highChart.CreateChart(message);

        byte[] file = highChart.getChartFile();
        using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(file)))
        {
            return image;
        }
    }
```

So now I return the image in Image format to my Controller.

My Client receives what comes from the controller. Here is the code (this is another application):

```
   IRestResponse response = client.Execute(requestCom);
```

So now my problem is, the client receives: 
response.content = System.Drawing.Bitmap
But i want it to receive a bitmap image, not just the type of it.
I use RestSharp for my client.

So how can I receive the image instead of the data type?

Thanks for help

Comment: you want to return `bitmap Image` so change your return type to `Bitmap`

Comment: What framework is the service written in? WCF?

Comment: Asp.net MVC @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [`File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx) method on your `Controller` and return an `ActionResult`.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetRequest([FromBody]ChartRequestModel body)
{
    ....
    // Creates Chart based on request
    await highChart.CreateChart(message);

    byte[] file = highChart.getChartFile();
    return File(file, "image/png"); //or image/jpg, etc.
}
```

Right now you are returning an object that isn't an `ActionResult` and ASP.NET MVC by default returns `ToString()` of anything that isn't an `ActionResult`.

Comment: Thank you it works. I didn't know that it returns a string by default. Good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried base64 encoding the bytes and sending that in your response as a parameter?